# CakePHP login redirect with url prefix glitch

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm using Cakephp 2.0 and I'm running into a little glitch as to where unauthorized users get redirected.
My CakePHP site has the login form at this url.

```
localhost/users/login
```

So if I try to visit localhost/users/dashboard, it redirects to the right login form.
However, if I try to visit a url that has a prefix, such as localhost/api/users/getInfo, it redirects to localhost/api/users/login instead (notice the extra prefix to the login form url)

How can I ensure that regardless of whether or not I'm using a prefix, unauthorized users will always get redirected to the correct login form?

Here is how I'm adding the component now.

```
public $components      = array('Auth' => array(
                                                    'loginRedirect' => array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'dashboard'),
                                                    'logoutRedirect' => '/',
                                                    'authError' => "You can't access that page",
                                                    'authorize' => array('Controller')
                                                    ));
```

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out.

I need to add this

```
'loginAction' => array('api' => false, 'controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login')
```

It's kinda hacky in that there is no 'prefix' => false, but instead I have to specify all the prefixes.